# How can I loop through multiple requests and return all the data

Tags: node.js

This is the snippet of code. Some small things have been changed.

```
app.get('/user/:username', async (req, res) => {


    axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}/users/${req.params.username}`, options)
        .then(userData => {

            let user = userData.data

            user.events.forEach(event => {

                if (event.type === 'Purchase') {
                    event.cart.forEach(async item => {
                        axios.get(item.url, options)
                            .then(itemData => {
                                item.itemData = itemData.data                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.log('ERROR', err)
                            })
                    })
                }

            })

            res.json({ events })
        })
})
```

I first hit the endpoint to grab the user data. Then I loop through the events array and if it is of type `purchase`, it loops through the cart array. The cart array contains items with a parameter called `url` which is another endpoint I need to hit. That then returns additional information and I add it onto the `item` object.

But when I look at `events`, it doesnt contain the new key/value I added. I am pretty sure this has something to do with async/promises. Would love some advice!

Comment: yup, I believe you have to use async in your loop ex: async.each or promise.all

Comment: Do you know what that will look like? I thought of doing `promise.all` but since I need to do the axios calls based on the amount of items there are in a cart, I cant seem to figure out what the code should look like.

Answer (score 1):

this is by no any means perfect, but the code should look something like this:

```
// Function to fetch info of item.
const fetchItemInfo = async (url) => {
  console.log(`Fetching ${url}`);
  const info = await axios(url); // API call to get item info.
  return {
    data: info.data
  };
}

// function to loop through the cart item and make them promise to be resolved
const getCartItemData = async (cart) => {
  // you can use for loop and use push to requests array, but I use map in this case
  const requests = cart.map(cartItem => {
    return fetchItemInfo(cartItem.url).then(info => {return info;});
  }
  return Promise.all(requests);
}

// then in your code, you can call the getCartItemData function like this:
if (event.type === 'Purchase') {
    getCartItemData(event.cart).then(itemData => console.log(itemData));
}
```